# CiviSurvey - User/Config Question

Tags: civisurvey

How best to survey all participants that attended a specific event?

I have successfully created some custom data fields, added them to a profile of type survey, and within Campaigns created a survey.

I am struggling with attaching survey respondents.  What I really would like to be able to do is an advanced contacts search (all contacts that attended a particular event) and then under the Activity menu have an option to 'Conduct Survey' and then select a particular survey.

OR

When I create a survey and get to the 'Reserve Respondents' section, have an additional field called 'Events', and when I select 1 (or more?) events, have the Respondents section populated with the event attendees.

Any thoughts or suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Drupal? Standard solution if so would be to create a webform and email all your participants a link.

Answer (score 1):

A Drupal solution we implemented recently was to put the survey/rating fields on the participant record, then set up a Scheduled Reminder to send a checksum link to a Webform that holds the fields.

However, I don't think putting the fields on Participant is probably the best solution for capturing data on people who attend but who were registered via a 'buy 5 tickets' type Price Field as we don't actually have the participant record in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use a group of Event Attendees in the meantime, and request the first option at issues.civicrm.org - including the exact URL link you'd like an action to. If you do add an issue then include a comment for me john@civifirst dotcom and I can take a look at it on the upcoming sprint.

Comment: A Drupal solution we implemented recently was to put the survey/rating fields on the participant record, then set up a Scheduled Reminder to send a checksum link to a Webform that holds the fields.